# Macbook pro won't start up and the apple logo is blue with stripes

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, gpu

The problem started a month ago. Suddenly my screen splits in half and the MBP shuts down and won't turn on. When I turn it on, it shows a blue or sometimes grey screen, or just stops loading.

I have tried <kbd>Cmd+Option+P+R</kbd> and it worked for sometimes and sometimes it didn't.

Now the logo itself turns blue with stripes (it was grey) and won't show any screen. The bar will just stop loading (also turning to blue) and my previous method won't work at all. Safe boot won't work and so is connecting to an external screen.

Comment: Can you identify the startup logo from this Apple Support page (it will help with troubleshooting): https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156

Comment: My immediate reaction is that you have a failing GPU.  It would helpful if you provided your machine model and OS you are running.  A screen capture or picture posted here would also be helpful.  Finally, try running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  Post your results so we can direct you further.

Comment: Progress indicator is shown with a bar and all of it appears blue! As for my model no. It's A1286 I forget the OS name but I regularly update so I think it's the recent one. I will try to upload the picture I don't know how on the phone. Tried the D key it's just grey screen for a while then the logo and the loading bar appeared as usual and froze in the middle. Thank you.

Comment: Don't know if this will help much, but does anything happen when you hold down the option key while turning on the computer? Also, as @Allan mentioned, pictures would be extremely helpful.

Comment: When booting, hold Cmd-V for [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573)  See if you can tell where the boot process is getting stuck.